# How to put divs for text field and button in one line (for mailchimp signup form)?

Tags: html, css-float, inline, mailchimp

I am trying to add a sign-up form (from mailchimp) for a newsletter to a web page and would like to place the text field and the button in one line (in the footer).

[http://jsfiddle.net/DW2Xd/](http://jsfiddle.net/DW2Xd/2/)

I have tried the suggestions given for similar questions, notably using "float-left" or "inline" styles, but am having no luck.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what your wanting but it sounds something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/DW2Xd/4/

Remove the display style on the form.

Hope this is what your looking for.